# Canon EOS 7DII - focus settings for birds in flight

Tags: autofocus, canon-7d, bird-photography

I recently acquired a vintage Canon EOS 7D Mark II with a low shutter count. Initially, I had very good results for birds in flight, but later I started experimenting with the very sophisticated autofocus settings with less than adequate results. I would of course shoot in AI FOCUS and AI SERVO.

What are the community's most successful autofocus settings for birds in flight using the EOS 7D Mark II, which has a much more sophisticated AF system with 65 cross-type AF points than earlier AF systems such as the 19 AF point system of the 7D?

Comment: Why would anyone ever shoot a Canon camera in AI Focus? That just means it will be in One Shot AF when you should be in AI Servo AF, and then it will switch to AI Servo AF when you'd be better off in One Shot AF. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but the accepted answer of the older question explains why the original 7D can't be used the way the 7D Mark II can be used because the 7D doesn't have have denser reticular AF system such as the 65-point reticular AF sensor in the 7D Mark II.